# ¿Cómo leer un archivo Json en android?

Tags: android, json, textview

Tengo un textview y en él quiero mostrar el contenido del Json pero no quiero mostrar todo lo que contiene solo una parte y no sé como hacerlo

```
{
"opt": {
"output_dir": "",
"num_to_draw": 10,
"final_nms_thresh": 0.3,
"use_cudnn": 1,
"text_size": 2,
"max_images": 100,
"gpu": -1,
"splits_json": "info/densecap_splits.json",
"vg_img_root_dir": "",
"checkpoint": "data/models/de/de-pre-v16.t7",
"num_proposals": 1000,
"rpn_nms_thresh": 0.7,
"image_size": 720,
"input_image": "imgs/elephant.jpg",
"input_split": "",
"box_width": 2,
"input_dir": "",
"output_vis_dir": "vis/data",
"output_vis": 1
},
"results": [
{
  "img_name": "elephant.jpg",
  "scores": [
    8.1914930343628,
    6.138174533844,
    1.7157821655273,
  ],
  "captions": [
    "people riding an elephant",
    "two people riding an elephant",
    "trunk of the elephant",
    "dirt on the ground",
    "head of an elephant",
  ],
  "boxes": [
    [
      290.14199829102,
      41.953628540039,
      173.92370605469,
      204.49822998047
    ],
    [
      215.09968566895,
      2.0242004394531,
      413.89117431641,
      481.68103027344
    ],
    [
      503.19287109375,
      230.57830810547,
      72.259887695312,
      192.77172851562
    ]
  ]
}
]
}
```

Solo necesito presentar lo que hay dentro del caption y no entiendo si lo tengo que hacer como arreglo o como objeto

Comment: ¿El `JSON` está en..? Se más específico :)

Comment: ¿El `JSON` es un `string` o es un archivo externo?

Answer (score 7):

> ¿Cómo leer un archivo Json en android?

Hay algo importante a considerar,

> - Si el .json inicia con { se considera como objeto Json.
> - Si el .json inicia con [ es considerado como Arreglo Json.

En tu pregunta tienes un archivo .Json que contiene un objeto (y dentro también arrays):

```
JSONObject jsonjObject = new JSONObject(RespuestaJson);
```

dentro de tu objeto puedes obtener sus valores de esta forma:

```
String valorLlave = jsonjObject.getString("<nombre llave>");
```

puedes también obtener todos los elementos de un array, por ejemplo el array `results`:

```
"results": [
{
  "img_name": "elephant.jpg",
  "scores": [
    8.1914930343628,
    6.138174533844,
    1.7157821655273,
  ],
  "captions": [
    "people riding an elephant",
    "two people riding an elephant",
    "trunk of the elephant",
    "dirt on the ground",
    "head of an elephant",
  ],
  "boxes": [
    [
      290.14199829102,
      41.953628540039,
      173.92370605469,
      204.49822998047
    ],
    [
      215.09968566895,
      2.0242004394531,
      413.89117431641,
      481.68103027344
    ],
    [
      503.19287109375,
      230.57830810547,
      72.259887695312,
      192.77172851562
    ]
  ]
```

se obtendrían sus elementos de esta forma, mediante el objeto `jsonjObject` que obtuviste :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonjObject.getJSONArray("results");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObjectHijo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("Parser JSON", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya tardó mucho tiempo tu _"Editando..."_ xD haha

Comment: @x4mp73r  gracias amigo, ahora olvidé eliminarlo! ﴾・⍘・﴿ haha!

Answer (score 2):

Si el `JSON` es un `string` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
String myJsonString= "{ text: 'some dummy text', array: [] }";
myJsonjObject = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
```

Y accedes a sus propiedades y objetos de la siguiente manera:

```
String myJsonString = myJsonjObject.getString("text"); // obtendrás 'some dummy text'
```

Para acceder al `array` dentro de `myJsonjObject` lo haces de la siguiente forma:

```
JSONArray myJsonArray = myJsonjObject.getJSONArray("array");
for (int i=0; i < myJsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject oneObject = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i); // Aquí accederías de la misma forma que se muestra arriba ya que es otro objeto
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la libreria `Gson` donde facilmente puedes convertir tu `String` (JSON) a una clase y asi poder acceder a los datos. por ejemplo;

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
  jsonData[] ojsonData= gson.fromJson(sJsonData, jsonData[].class);
```

Donde jsonData, es la clase que creaste anteriormente con los mismos datos de tu json cada uno con su metodo `get` y `set`, y sJsonData es tu Json (`String`) y para acceder a cada elemento solo con:

```
 ojsonData[0].getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("list");

System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + jArray.length());

for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    Log.i("log_tag", "_id" + json_data.getInt("account") +
        ", mall_name" + json_data.getString("name") +
        ", location" + json_data.getString("number") +
        ", telephone" + json_data.getString("url") +
        ",----" + json_data.getString("balance") +
        ",----" + json_data.getString("credit") +
        ",----" + json_data.getString("displayName")
    );
}
```

revisa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244879/reading-a-json-array-in-android

Comment: Creo que te confundes, la pregunta es relacionada a Android.

Comment: @x4mp73r cierto me confundi de lenguaje

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que el JSON es una variable:

```
JSONObject fullObject = new JSONObject(tu_json);
JSONObject resultsObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("results");
String  imgName = uniObject.getJsonString("img_name");
```

Esto extrae el objeto `results` (del objeto JSON) en la variable `resultsObject` y después extrae el atributo `img_name` de ese objeto (`resultsObject`) en la variable `imgName`, que es una cadena de texto.

Comment: En realidad si te fijas `results` es un array, no un objeto.

Comment: @Error404 y es la única respuesta con 1 hehe ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Elenasys It's suspicious ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

Voy a desglosar tu JSON. En realidad lo que tienes es un objeto que engloba todo el JSON, el cual contiene objetos y arrays.

Para detectar si lo que quieres recuperar es un objeto o un array te tienes que fijar en las llaves que lo engloban, si utiliza corchetes cuadrados `[]` hará referencia a un Array y si utiliza corchetes `{}` hará referencia a un objeto.

Por tanto, como quieres recuperar solamente "captions" puedes observar que este es un array ya que su contenido está definido por corchetes cuadrados `[]`. A su vez, "captions" está dentro del contenido de un objeto el cual está contenido del array "results" y a su vez este está dentro del objeto que engloba a todo el JSON.

En caso de que tengas tu JSON como String voy a traducir lo anterior a código:

```
String json = "aqui tu JSON";
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json); //Obtenemos el JSON global
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("results"); //Obtenemos el array results
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) //Miramos en todos los objetos del array de objetos results
{
    try {
        JSONObject objeto = jArray.getJSONObject(i); //Obtenemos cada uno de los objetos del array results
        JSONArray jArrayCaptions = objeto.getJSONArray("captions"); //Obtenemos el array captions dentro de cada uno de los objetos del array results

        for(int j = 0; j < jArrayCaptions; j++){
            jArrayCaptions.getString(i); //Obtenemos cada uno de los String del array captions
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
}
```