# Problemas al listar un JSONArray en AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, arraylist

tengo un json que me da este resultado:

```
{
   "error": false,
   "fatigas": [
      {
         "fatServ_fecha": "2018-01-07",
         "fatServ_HoraIn": "10:13:00",
         "fatServ_HoraOut": null,
         "turn_cod": "3",
         "are_cod": "62",
         "fatServ_cerrar": "D",
         "fatServ_imprimir": "D",
         "fatServ_validacion": "D"
      }
   ]
}
```

y aquí está el código dónde lo imprimo, el problema es que no entra al for

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
            ((Activity) getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if(jsonObject!=null){
                            items = new ArrayList<>();
                            JSONArray resultados = jsonObject.getJSONArray("respuesta");
                            for (int i = 0; i < resultados.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject fatigas = resultados.getJSONObject(i);
                                items.add(new Fatigas(fatigas.getString("fatServ_fecha")+"",
                                        fatigas.getString("fatServ_HoraIn")+"",
                                        fatigas.getString("fatServ_HoraOut")+"",
                                        fatigas.getString("turn_cod")+"",
                                        fatigas.getString("are_cod")+"",
                                        fatigas.getString("fatServ_cerrar"),
                                        fatigas.getString("fatServ_imprimir"),
                                        fatigas.getString("fatServ_validacion")));
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No hay fatigas",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    FatigasAdapter adapter = new FatigasAdapter(items);
                    rv_listado.setAdapter(adapter);
                    rv_listado.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),1));
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Juan, estas seguro que ese es el json completo?, no entra porque no es un jsonArray es un jsonObject. Te recomiendo confirmar si la variable "s" es la que contiene el json?

Comment: @Jorgesys si, el array está completo.

Comment: OK Juan, revisa mi respuesta, en realidad tratas de buscar un array llamado "respuesta", el nombre de array debe ser "fatigas".

Answer (score 0):

No entra porque no existe un Array  llamanado "respuesta"

```
JSONArray resultados = jsonObject.getJSONArray("respuesta");
```

En realidad tienes un objeto que dentro tiene un Array llamado "fatigas", de aquí es donde debes obtener los objetos (en el caso del ejemplo que muestras es solo uno):

```
...
...
     JSONArray resultados = jsonObject.getJSONArray("fatigas");
                                for (int i = 0; i < resultados.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject fatigas = resultados.getJSONObject(i);
                                    items.add(new Fatigas(fatigas.getString("fatServ_fecha")+"",
                                            fatigas.getString("fatServ_HoraIn")+"",
                                            fatigas.getString("fatServ_HoraOut")+"",
                                            fatigas.getString("turn_cod")+"",
                                            fatigas.getString("are_cod")+"",
                                            fatigas.getString("fatServ_cerrar"),
                                            fatigas.getString("fatServ_imprimir"),
                                            fatigas.getString("fatServ_validacion")));
                                }
...
...
```

Te sugiero revisar:

[¿Cómo leer un archivo Json en android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34515/c%C3%B3mo-leer-un-archivo-json-en-android/34520#34520)