# Cómo iterar JsonObject

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero iterear el siguiente JsonObject:

```
{"datos":"[{\"Id_empresas\":\"160\",\"0\":\"160\",\"Nombre\":\"Vidrería M-M\",\"1\":\"Vidrería M-M\",\"Ruc\":\"24545788-6]}
```

lo recibo en volley:

```
 JsonObjectRequest request  =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ruta, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                   JSONObject jsonjObject = new JSONObject(response);//aqui me marca error el compilador



                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.i(Constantes.TAG, "onErrorResponse: "+error.getMessage());
            Log.i(Constantes.TAG, "onErrorResponse getNetworkTimeMs "+error.getNetworkTimeMs());

        }
    });
```

Quiero sacar el JsonArray que se encuentra dentro del JsonObject.

GRacias

Comment: Hola consulta este linck https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/34515/c%C3%B3mo-leer-un-archivo-json-en-android

Comment: Me marca error el compilador en response JSONObject jsonjObject = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: aqui utilizan volley https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131856/obtener-datos-en-respuesta-json-usando-volley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que econtré fue que tiene comillas doble "\", lo corregí en mi php que genera los datos desde el servidor, luego recorri de esta manera desde mi app movil:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("datos");
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        Log.i(Constantes.TAG,"jsonArray ok "+object.getString("Id_empresas"));
```

Agradezco a todos aquellos que han intentado ayudarme!!

Answer (score 0):

En la variable `response` ya tienes el `JSONObject`, a partir de ahí lo recorres:

```
JSONArray jsarr = response.getJSONArray("datos");
for (int i=O; i<jsarr.length; i++) {
   // Iteras sobre los elementos
}
```

Nota: el ejemplo de `json` que presentas tiene una apertura de llave dentro del array que no se cierra, así que no sé si dentro tienes un objeto y falta cerrarlo o es un array y sobra la llave. Según sea lo recorres, pero si no está bien formado dará error.